CSS Resize grid cell based on image content
I have the following basic HTML + CSS of a grid with 2 columns and 3 rows:
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-container upload-area" id="upload-area">
    <img src="https://www.flickr.com/photos/76283671@N00/157839004/" alt="img">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--background);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.upload-area {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.upload-area img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

I want to display an image that the user uploads in a cell in the center row.
With .inner-container set to overflow: hidden and .img set to max-width: 100%, max-height: 100%, and object-fit: contain, the image is correctly resized to fit the cell.
However, if a large image is uploaded, I first want .container to grow to its maximum height and then resize the image. To achieve this, I set a width and max-width for .container and specified the center row to 1fr. Yet, this is not working. The center row, and the container overall never grow.
What am I doing wrong?

Can you provide a working [mcve], your code is a little confusing and the image 404s
